# SQL Server display messages like a conversation

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing a information system, and I've and message center. And I want to display the messages like Outlook or Gmail "conversation".

In my message table I have the following columns:

- MessageId (PK)
- Date
- From (FK)
- To (FK)
- Body
- Subject
- State
- Subject
- ReplyId (FK), null

First I get the messages that don't have `replyId`, to show the "latest" message.

But I don't get the conversation, when any one click on message... :(

Any one could help me with the query?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I add an extra field to the table, the Id of last reply to the conversation, so I can get all conversation message at one time!

:)

Comment: 1.  Can you show your current query you are using?  2. Can replies be to message in the middle of the conversation, or only to the start of the conversation?  i.e., if you search for replyId = messageId, will you always get all the replies.

Comment: My query: 

`declare @messageId int = 4

select reply.*
from Messages as m
inner join Messages as reply on m.MessageId = reply.ReplyId 
where m.MessageId = @messageId`

I only get the reply to messageId = 4... But, messageId = 1 is reply to messageId = 2, messageId = 2 is reply to messageId = 3, and so on...

Thanks!

Comment: It's *usually* better to have reply messages hold the message ID that they're a reply to, rather than the other way round - your current model lets two messages receive the same reply message (somewhat unusual), and no message can be replied to more than once - in such a model, the original message in the conversation has a null value, and then you search down into replies from there. Having every message in the conversation *also* reference the original message can improve things though.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Agreed wholeheartedly--my answer assumed it was your way, not the way the user has it. That's a little dangerous (especially with email). OP will want to seriously consider damien's suggestions.

Comment: I've always confused over it... :(
How you sugested to be?

Comment: Children should have a FK to the parent, parents shouldn't have FK to children (in one-to-many relationships). In this case, your `replyid` column should really be a `parentid` column and have it point to the message that the reply replied to.

Comment: Thanks again from the explain. :)
Now I've problems defining the trigger to do the right tree in `hierarchyid`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `CTE` to accomplish this, which is essentially a parent-child query:

```
declare @MessageId int = 3;

with Conversations as
(
    select
        MessageId,
        [Date],
        [From],
        [To],
        Body,
        [Subject],
        [State],
        ReplyId,
        CAST(MessageId as varchar(max)) + '-' as hierarchy,
        CAST(MessageId as varchar(max)) + '-' as TopMessageId
    from
        Messages
    where
        replyid is null
    union all
    select
        m.MessageId,
        m.[Date],
        m.[From],
        m.[To],
        m.Body,
        m.[Subject],
        m.[State],
        m.ReplyId,
        c.hierarchy + CAST(m.MessageId as varchar(max)) + '-' as hierarchy,
        c.TopMessageId
    from
        Conversations c
        inner join Messages m on
            c.MessageId = m.ReplyId
)

select
    c2.MessageId,
    c2.[Date],
    c2.[From],
    c2.[To],
    c2.Body,
    c2.[Subject],
    c2.[State],
    c2.ReplyId
from
    Conversations c1
    inner join Conversations c2 on
        c2.hierarchy like c1.TopMessageId + '%'
where
    c1.MessageId = @MessageId
order by c2.[Date] desc
```

If you're using SQL Server 2008, you may want to look into using a [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) column on your table to avoid the CTE all together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I'm using SQL Server 2008, but I've never used `hierarchyid`... I'm going to read the documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is making recursion with sql server because you want you have the conversation as a child parent relation ship.

Answer (score 0):

i've write this, its a easy chat  conversion:

```
 session_start();
 $regreg = $_SESSION['username'];
 $fgetrhge = $_GET['with'];

 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TESTDB', 'TESTUSER', 'TESTPASS');

 $sql = "SELECT an, von, message, time FROM messages ORDER BY time ASC";

 foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

 if($_SESSION['username'] == $row['von'] && $_GET['with'] == $row['an']) {
 echo '<div align="right">
 <div class="own">

 <span style="margin-right:18px;" class="nmespn">DU</span>
 <img src="http://YOURDOMAIN.NET/profileicons/'.$regreg.'" class="pbmspna" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='."'http://crashhd.de/no_pic.png'".';">
 <div style="float:left;padding-top:2px;" align="left">
 <span class="tmespn">'.$row['time'].'</span>
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <div align="left" style="margin-left:14px" class="msgspn">
 <span>'.$row['message'].'</span>
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 <br>';
}
 else if($_GET['with'] == $row['von'] && $_SESSION['username']  == $row['an']) {

 echo '<div align="left">
 <div align="left" class="partner">
 <img src="http://YOURDOMAIN.NET/profileicons/'.$row['von'].'" class="pbmspna" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='."'http://crashhd.de/no_pic.png'".';">
 <span class="nmespn" style="cursor:pointer;">'.$row['von'].'</span>
 <div style="float:right;padding-right:6px;" align="right">
 <span class="tmespn">'.$row['time'].'</span>
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <div class="msgspn">
 <span>'.$row['message'].'</span>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <br>';
    }
 }

 // an = to; von = from; sry im german :D
```

I hope I could help :)